# Why won't this work? - using .blit through a variable

Tags: python-2.7, variables, pygame

Using a variable to print something should work in python. Why does it not work when I run my code? The variable name is bliting. If this issue can be solved what can I do? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
image = pygame.image.load("o1.png")
bliting = window.blit(image, (0,0))
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop = False

#why does typing in the variable name "bliting" not blit my image?
    bliting

    window.fill((255,255,255))
    pygame.display.flip()
 pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you reference a variable without doing any operation on it? Are you looking for it to call `window.blit(image, (0,0))` - if so you need wrap it in a `lambda` and call it, e.g. `bliting = lambda: window.blit(image, (0,0))`, then call it in your loop: `bliting()`

Comment: Yes, that was what I was looking to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does, the problem is you are only blitting the image once, then the screen is being filled with white continuously. Try the code bellow.

```python
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
image = pygame.image.load("o1.png")
bliting = window.blit(image, (0,0))
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop = False

    bliting

    pygame.display.flip()
 pygame.quit()
```

Notice how all I did was remove the screen fill. And while this "works" a better alternative would be to create a function that blits the images and call that in your loop.

Also, for future reference, make sure you are blitting images after your screen.fill() and not before. While it didn't matter in this situation, it is a simple mistake people often skip over.

Feel free to let me know if you have any similar problems :)